# spring boot app running on tomcat is giving 404 error for static contents under internet explorer

Tags: tomcat, spring-boot, internet-explorer-11

I have a **spring boot** app deployed on **tomcat** server as a **war** generated with **maven** and I have an issue with **static contents under internet explorer**.

After navigating inside the app, requesting a static content file returns ***a 404 error*** only the first time because when I refresh the window the static content is displayed successfully. This only happens under Internet Explorer (chrome is working fine).

I am serving these static files from the src/main/resources/static/ folder.

I am running out of ideas so any help is much appreciated.

Comment: does it happen everytime when you restart internet-explorer or is it maybe just a cached response? What is the test environment? Is it deployed localy on your machine or on a remote machine behind a webserver?

Comment: It happens everytime we have a new file, once I get the 404 error and refresh, all the other static resources are displayed from the first try including the new file. The app is deployed to a remote machine and tomcat is the only AS. I don't know if it is worth mentionning that the files under src/main/resources/static/ are created at runtime by the java web services.